# How do I have a form save users data after being incorrectly filled

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to have my form where, if the user enters data and it is incorrect it will send them back to the form to fix there mistakes.  My problem is it always then wipes all the other content out.  Is there a way for me to have that auto saved and just have what needs fixing get reset?

I know I could probably use $_POST but I was wondering if there is a faster way.

Thank You for your time!

Answer (score 2):

you can make a Javascript validator, that alerts you, if all the required inputs arent filled, but with JS disabled, you would still have to use  $_POST to refill the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Save the $_POST data to a session variable before sending the user back. Load the data from that variable on the form page and use it to fill in the fields (and of course `unset` that variable when you don't need the data anymore).

Answer (score 1):

For the first, you should use [html5 input type](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_input_types.asp)s, so that you need not to validate input fields using javascript.

Secondly, use required attribute for the required fields.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The question is not about client-side validation, it's about server-side validation using PHP (at least that's how I interpret it).

Comment: Ok I understand. Please let me know that you read this, and I will remove my answer.